# SQL Server 2012 Management Studio Intellisense not working over VPN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

I am on a company laptop and intellisense works flawlessly while at the office. However, when I connect to the company network via VPN (using same comp laptop), I am able to see the various DBs and objects as well as query those DBs. The only thing missing is intellisense...

Anyone else experience this? Do I need to open a port in my router?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: FWIW SSMS's intellisense seems rather flaky. It typically works only a fraction of the time for me regardless of how I'm connected.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same problem sometime back.
It has something to deal with Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Download and install that.

Once you install that, it should start working. I dont know why and how, but I had read about this on some site and it indeed worked for me.

Do reply about the result.

kind Regards,
Ashay (India)